# Unable to allocate free space at end of disk to Mac

Tags: macos, diskutil

As per screenshot below, my Mac has 1TB storage, but the actual capacity shown in Disk Utility only 816GB. There is 200GB categorised as "free space" when I performed a `diskutil list`, however I can't run any scripts to allocate it. My OS is Big Sur, can anyone advise me?

[image: About This Mac: Storage]

Please see below the diskutil list result:

[image: diskutil list]

Comment: Can you add at your question the results of `diskutil list` command?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the Windows Recovery partition disk0s3 is useless.
So you can try this commands :

```
diskutil erasevolume free space disk0s3
```

Then

```
diskutil ap resizecontainer disk2 0b
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly....

Comment: I'm happy for you. ;)